# If I leave a player's realm, will my buildings and chests be deleted?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Will my inventory, buildings and chests be deleted if I leave a players realm on  Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Answer (score -2):

Buildings and Chests are blocks so they can't be deleted,
but your iventory are gonna be deleted.
If you want to keep your iventory put it in a chest before to leave.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Are you sure player inventory is not saved?  It *is* saved on normal Minecraft servers.  I haven't played Realms, but I did some searching. 
 [Here's someone reporting](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/REALMS-456) their inventory not being saved on Realms *as a bug*, which implies the normal functionality of Realms is to save player inventories.